# C++ ffmpeg API created video does not open in some players

Tags: c++, video, ffmpeg, codec

After my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47321509/video-creation-with-the-most-recent-ffmpeg-api-2017), I found codes from [here](http://ttps://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/doc/examples/encode_video.c) to create videos in `C++` using `avcodec` of `ffmpeg` libraries.

I have modified this code to comply with `C++`. Everything is fine and it creates `mp4` videos. Except for the output video opens with some video managers and does not open with some others.

E.g. I can open it on Linux by totem (the slider does not allow back and forth anyway). But VLC (on the same Linux machine) does not open this file. Probably, there will be similar problem in windows.

Is there any missing process for this code causing this problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

extern "C" {
    #include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
    #include <libavutil/opt.h>
    #include <libavutil/imgutils.h>
}

static void encode(AVCodecContext *enc_ctx, AVFrame *frame, AVPacket *pkt,
                   FILE *outfile)
{
    int ret;

    /* send the frame to the encoder */
    if (frame)
        std::cout<<"Send frame "<<(frame->pts)<<std::endl;

    ret = avcodec_send_frame(enc_ctx, frame);
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error sending a frame for encoding\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while (ret >= 0) {
        ret = avcodec_receive_packet(enc_ctx, pkt);
        if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF)
            return;
        else if (ret < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error during encoding\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        std::cout<<"Write packet "<<(pkt->pts)<<" (size="<<(pkt->size)<<")"<<std::endl;
        // printf("Write packet %3" PRId64" (size=%5d)\n", pkt->pts, pkt->size);
        fwrite(pkt->data, 1, pkt->size, outfile);
        av_packet_unref(pkt);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const char *filename;
    const AVCodec *codec;
    AVCodecContext *c= NULL;
    int i, ret, x, y;
    FILE *f;
    AVFrame *frame;
    AVPacket *pkt;
    uint8_t endcode[] = { 0, 0, 1, 0xb7 };

    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <output file>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(0);
    }
    filename = argv[1];
    std::string codec_name = "mpeg4";

    avcodec_register_all();

    /* find the mpeg1video encoder */
    codec = avcodec_find_encoder_by_name(codec_name.c_str());
    if (!codec) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Codec '%s' not found\n", codec_name.c_str());
        exit(1);
    }

    c = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
    if (!c) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate video codec context\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    pkt = av_packet_alloc();
    if (!pkt)
        exit(1);

    /* put sample parameters */
    // c->bit_rate = 400000;
    c->bit_rate = 4000000;
    /* resolution must be a multiple of two */
    // c->width = 352;
    // c->height = 288;
    c->width = 640;
    c->height = 480;
    /* frames per second */
    c->time_base = (AVRational){1, 25};
    c->framerate = (AVRational){25, 1};

    /* emit one intra frame every ten frames
     * check frame pict_type before passing frame
     * to encoder, if frame->pict_type is AV_PICTURE_TYPE_I
     * then gop_size is ignored and the output of encoder
     * will always be I frame irrespective to gop_size
     */
    c->gop_size = 10;
    c->max_b_frames = 1;
    c->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;

    if (codec->id == AV_CODEC_ID_H264)
        av_opt_set(c->priv_data, "preset", "slow", 0);

    /* open it */
    ret = avcodec_open2(c, codec, NULL);
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open codec\n");
        // fprintf(stderr, "Could not open codec: %s\n", av_err2str(ret));
        exit(1);
    }

    f = fopen(filename, "wb");
    if (!f) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s\n", filename);
        exit(1);
    }

    frame = av_frame_alloc();
    if (!frame) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate video frame\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    frame->format = c->pix_fmt;
    frame->width  = c->width;
    frame->height = c->height;

    ret = av_frame_get_buffer(frame, 32);
    if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate the video frame data\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* encode 10 second of video */
    for (i = 0; i < 250; i++) {
        fflush(stdout);

        /* make sure the frame data is writable */
        ret = av_frame_make_writable(frame);
        if (ret < 0)
            exit(1);

        /* prepare a dummy image */
        /* Y */
        for (y = 0; y < c->height; y++) {
            for (x = 0; x < c->width; x++) {
                frame->data[0][y * frame->linesize[0] + x] = uint8_t(x + y + i * 3);
            }
        }

        /* Cb and Cr */
        for (y = 0; y < c->height/2; y++) {
            for (x = 0; x < c->width/2; x++) {
                frame->data[1][y * frame->linesize[1] + x] = uint8_t(128 + y + i * 2);
                frame->data[2][y * frame->linesize[2] + x] = uint8_t(64 + x + i * 5);
            }
        }

        frame->pts = i;

        /* encode the image */
        encode(c, frame, pkt, f);
    }

    /* flush the encoder */
    encode(c, NULL, pkt, f);

    /* add sequence end code to have a real MPEG file */
    fwrite(endcode, 1, sizeof(endcode), f);
    fclose(f);

    avcodec_free_context(&c);
    av_frame_free(&frame);
    av_packet_free(&pkt);

    return 0;
}
```

build:

```
g++ -I ./FFmpeg/ video.cpp -L ./fflibs -lavdevice -lavfilter -lavformat -lavcodec -lrt -ldl -lXfixes -lXext -lX11 -lasound -lSDL -lz -lrt -lswresample -lswscale -lavutil -lm -llzma -lbz2 -lswresample -lpthread
```

run

```
./a.out myvideo.mp4
```

This video will be fine if converted in bash via

```
ffmpeg -i myvideo.mp4 out1.mp4
```

But I look for a method to fix it from the code.

Generated video played on totem (Ubuntu):

[image: c++ ffmpeg avcodec]

Video after conversion:

[image: converted]

Comment: See this muxing example and set your pts properly
https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.8/muxing_8c-example.html

Comment: @Ankur, I dont understand what is wrong with my pts.

Comment: You are incrementing pts by 1 . It is actually a relation between codec time base and stream time base.
There are multiple ways to set pts. 
But this answer should point you in the right direction. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595288/understanding-pts-and-dts-in-video-frames

Comment: I am new to frames, videos and codecs. I still did not catch what to do. Should I scale an integer? sounds unrealistic.

Comment: Read the answer in the link and muxing example. They explain it better

Comment: `frame->pts = codec->pts`  ??

Comment: frame->pts += av_rescale_q(1, video_st->codec->time_base, video_st->time_base); }

Try setting your pts like this.  Where video_st is your stream.

Comment: Codec time base is avrational 1/framerate. 
Stream timebase can be anything like 1/90000 for voip. Or 1/128000. Depends on the stream

Comment: @Ankur, Many thanks. It requires a stream. I am wondering `AVStream *outStream =???`. The line `AVStream *outStream = avformat_new_stream(c, codec);` does give me error: cannot convert ‘AVCodecContext*’ to ‘AVFormatContext*

Comment: You may not want stream . Those structures are avrational

Comment: @Ankur, I use `frame->pts += av_rescale_q(1, c->time_base, c->time_base);` which compiles fine but it gives me `[mpeg4 @ 0x36f7c20] time_incr 18077809191891763200 too large` shouldn't I run `av_rescale_q` to add value to `pkt.pts` like [here](https://github.com/rvs/ffmpeg/blob/master/libavformat/output-example.c)?

Comment: In place of second c->timebase use avrational {1,128000}

Comment: @Ankur, used `frame->pts += av_rescale_q(1, c->time_base, (AVRational){1,128000});` which compiled fine but in run time gave me so many `[mpeg4 @ 0x2cd2c20] time_incr 18077809191891763610 too large`, then `[mpeg4 @ 0x39cec20] Internal error, picture buffer overflow` and finally `Aborted (core dumped)`

Comment: Try 12800. I don't remember the correct value

Comment: Then try muxing example. Comment the audio part

Comment: @Ankur Please if you can throw some light on this as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48055979/mux-audio-and-video-ffmpeg-c

Comment: @ar2015 Did you get this resolved?

Comment: @Valgrind1691, I still use ffmpeg to convert the video! Then I open it.

Comment: @ar2015 Means you got this working?

Comment: @Valgrind1691, Means C code does not work. I just get around it by ffmpeg in the linux shell not the C library of ffmpeg.

Comment: okay, seems you went the executable way